# Checking HTML document with REST Assured

Tags: rest-assured

I'm trying to use [REST Assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured) to check some properties on an HTML document returned by my server. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem would be as follows:

```java
import static com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.config.XmlPathConfig.xmlPathConfig;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath;

public class HtmlDocumentTest {

  @Test
  public void titleShouldBeHelloWorld() {
    final XmlPath xml = new XmlPath("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">"
      + "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">"
      + "<head><title>Hello world</title></head><body></body></html>")
      .using(xmlPathConfig().with().feature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", false));
    assertThat(xml.get("//title[text()]"), is("Hello world"));
  }
}
```

Now, this attempt ends in `com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.exception.XmlPathException: Failed to parse the XML document` caused by, off all the possible errors, `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out` after some 30 seconds or so!

If I remove the line with the `xmlPathConfig().with().feature(...)` the test fails immediately due to `DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.`.

If I remove the doctype line from the document the parsing succeeds but the test fails on an assertion error, "`Expected: is "Hello world" but: was <Hello worldnull>`" -- however, that's a different problem, obviously (but feel free to give instructions on that one, too...). And removing the doctype isn't an option for me anyway.

So, question: how do you check properties of an HTML document with a doctype using REST Assured? It says [in the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Custom_parsers) that "*REST Assured providers predefined parsers for e.g. HTML, XML and JSON.*", but I cannot seem to find any examples on how exactly to activate and work with that HTML parser! There's no "`HtmlPath`" class like there's `XmlPath`, for example, and that timeout exception is very puzzling...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I checked your code. The thing is that XmlPath of Restassured isn't Xpath, but uses a property access syntax. If you add a body content to your sample HTML you will see that your XPath doesn't do much. The actual name of the query language is [GPath](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath). The following example works, note also the use of CompatibilityMode.HTML, which has the right config for you need:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath;
import com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath.CompatibilityMode;

public class HtmlDocumentTest {

    @Test
    public void titleShouldBeHelloWorld() {
        XmlPath doc = new XmlPath(
                CompatibilityMode.HTML,
                "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">"
                        + "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">"
                        + "<head><title>Hello world</title></head>"
                        + "<body>some body"
                        + "<div class=\"content\">wrapped</div>"
                        + "<div class=\"content\">wrapped2</div>"
                        + "</body></html>");

        String title = doc.getString("html.head.title");
        String content = doc.getString("html.body.div.find { it.@class == 'content' }");
        String content2 = doc.getString("**.findAll { it.@class == 'content' }[1]");

        assertEquals("Hello world", title);
        assertEquals("wrapped", content);
        assertEquals("wrapped2", content2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/58301335/6648326 ?

Answer (score 11):

If you're using the DSL (given/when/then) then XmlPath with `CompatibilityMode.HTML` is used automatically if the response content-type header contains a `html` compatible media type (such as `text/html`). For example if `/index.html` contains the following html page:

```
<html>
    <title>My page</title>
    <body>Something</body>
</html>
```

then you can validate the title and body like this:

```
when().
        get("/index.html").
then().
        statusCode(200).
        body("html.title", equalTo("My page"), 
             "html.body",  equalTo("Something"));
```

Comment: Why not use this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/58301335/6648326 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code with the latest rest assured apis, i.e. io.restassured and not the older jayway.restassured. The explanation for the code is in the code comments.

```
//Demo for an api which returns a json string inside html. The json string is just an array of objects.

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

import java.util.List;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

public void testMyApi() {
    Response response =
            when().
                    get("www.myapi.com/data").
            then().
                    extract().
                    response();
    
    String bodyTxt = response.htmlPath().getString("body");//Get the body element of the html response.
    JsonPath jsonObj = new JsonPath(bodyTxt);//helps us to find things in a json string.

    List<String> rootItems = jsonObj.getList("$");//get root element of the json part.

    System.out.println(rootItems);
}
```