# java REST Assured response body with Content-Type: text/html with injected html tags

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

Let's say someone developed rest api that returns data in json format but he didn't set response `Content-Type` to `application/json` but `text/html`.

Now I have test written in REST Assured:

```
    given()
    .param("username", username)
    .param("password", password)
.when()
    .get("/authenticate")
.then()
    .statusCode(200)
    .body("user.id" , hasItem(20));
```

but it doesn't work. I logged out response body and and that's what I get:

```
<html>
    <body>{"key":"752E7A74E8F3999BE9EFE3EA0E0DF320","user":{"id":20,"firstName":"K1","lastName":"K1","role":"ROLE_CUSTOMER","phoneNumber":"888888888"},"expirationDate":"2016-08-10T13:52:50+02:00"}</body>
</html>
```

and the error:

```
FAILED: test_login_as_valid_customer("888888888", "3432")
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path key doesn't match.
Expected: 20
  Actual:
```

Between body tags there is my expected json but where did html tags come from? I cant't see them in response when I test api method in Postman or Paw or even in web browser (since it is simple GET with url params).

I suspect I get error "JSON path key doesn't match." because of those tags.

Answer (score 4):

3 years passed from the original question, I'm having the same issue and here's what I've got.

#### 1 - logging issue

Wrapping the response body into html tags is a work of `io.restassured.internal.support.Prettifier` class.
You can disable it the following way.

```
    RestAssured.requestSpecification.expect()
        .log().body(false) // `shouldPrettyPrint` parameter set to false
```

But it affects only logging, not actual response body.

#### 2 - matching issue

Assertions on response body mind it's content-type. If some API gives invalid headers and there's no way to fix it on the server side, you can work it around on the client side. In case of RestAssured, it can be done with a filter:

```
    static final Filter FORCE_JSON_RESPONSE_BODY = (reqSpec, respSpec, ctx) -> {
        Response response = ctx.next(reqSpec, respSpec);
        ((RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl) response).setContentType("application/json");
        return response;
    };

    // globally
    RestAssured.filters(FORCE_JSON_RESPONSE_BODY);

    // or per request
    Response response = RestAssured
        .given()
        .filters(FORCE_JSON_RESPONSE_BODY)
        .get("something")
```

Comment: Note, that RestAssured docs https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#filters suggest to use Response Builder to alter the response.

Also, you can use ContentType.JSON constant instead of "application/json" literal

Comment: Will this code work correctly when the response is *not* json and *not* html ? If not, then how do we handle that scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;

RestAssured.given()
     .header("Accept", "application/json")
     .when()
     .get(endpoint)
     .then()
     .statusCode(200)
     .contentType(ContentType.JSON);
```

The above header provides the header parameter. Once, the request is processed it checks for the status code 200 and the content type as JSON.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on how your endpoints are implemented, the format of the data returned may depend on the value of `Accept` header the client sent. So check exactly what headers you are sending when you test with Postman and in your RESTAssured test — they may well differ, and your endpoint might be returning HTML if you do not explicitly specify `Accept: application/json` in your request.

Comment: In Postman I do not specify Accept header. When I tried in RESTAssured test - given().accept(ContentType.JSON) it returned text/html anyway

Comment: I just tried to execute similar test with api that returns Content-Type: application/json and it passed. Target variable in json was found and properly extracted for assertion.

Answer (score -2):

The html tags come from the Content-Type being text/html, so the json data is recognised as text and is wrapped in the body of an html. If you inspect the text in the browser you will probably see the html tags.

Comment: I have inspected response in browser and there was no html tags.